# Unsuccessful in executing swagger code gen

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

Installed Java Version 8 Update 271.

Downloaded the swagger-codegen-cli version 2.4.17 from this [link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.4.17/swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.17.jar)

When i run the command to generate i get the below issues

I have to use this [JSON](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-models/main/models/sellers-api-model/sellers.json) but i also tested with this sample [JSON](http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json)

For 2.4.7 rc1 I get the below error:

[image]

Tried finding the step by step. Never found one.

Any pointers is helpful

- Shankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://petstore.swagger.io/petstore.json returns 404.

Please use https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml instead, e.g.

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml -l csharp -o C:\test\csharp-client
```